# Video editor exporting mp4 video black

Tags: export, video-sequence-editor, video

I edited a video and it looks great in the preview window, when I scan the video I can see all the clips.  But when I export it, there's a section of my video that turns black.  The video disappears but my audio and image overlay stays.
Sometimes when I watch the preview, some clips turn black randomly.   Very glitchy.  I've been having so many glitchy problems with Blender this weekend and I have the version 3.3.1.

I haven't changed any settings and I've exported several videos before this one just fine.  I've restarted my computer and closed and reopened Blender.  But the same thing happens.

What do I need to do?

Comment: You should try the proxy

Comment: I use a proxy to edit the videos and it's never turned black before.  What should I do with the proxy?